# Como puedo realizar programa para sumar números de array pero con función recursiva?

Tags: c++

Estoy muy confundido de los parámetros para crear arrays, punteros y funciones recursivas pero tengo que crear el siguiente programa en c++: Diseñar una función de nombre sum que, dado un puntero "a" entero que apunta a la primera posición de un array de números enteros y un entero "n" con la longitud del array dado, devuelva la suma de todos sus valores mediante una función recursiva.

A continuación diseña un programa que lea un número entero n, que representa el número de valores que se leerán a continuación y, a continuación lea n valores que hay que almacenar en un array. Finalmente, muestra por pantalla el resultado de la suma de todos los valores del array.

Ejemplo de Entrada 1

0

Ejemplo de Salida 1

0

Ejemplo de Entrada 2

4
1 2 3 4

Ejemplo de Salida 2

10

La estructura básica del programa es esta:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int sum(int a, int n);
int main(){
  int n=0;
  cin >> n;
}
int sum(int a, int n){


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La recursividad puede ser algo muy complicado en un inicio, pero la practica y constancia programando harán que esta se vea mas fácil cada vez.

En mi criterio podría decir que la recursividad tiene dos partes importantes.

**El caso base:** Que generalmente es una condicional(`if`) que indica/retorna el valor final de nuestra función recursiva. En tu caso por ejemplo tienes datos de entrada donde `0` es un valor final de tu recursividad.
**El cuerpo o la recursividad:** Esta quiza sea la parte mas complicada, ya aqui es donde debemos hacer la llamada a nuestra funcion implementando la logica para conseguir nuestro objetivo. La llamada a dicha funcion desde la misma funcion, pueden ser de 1,2,3... y cuantas veces lo requiera tu problema(alguna vez utilice 8 en la ACM).

**La solucion a tu problema**

```
int sum(int a, int n){
    if(n==0){//caso base
        return 0;
    } 
    return sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1];//recursividad
}
```

Ahora analicemos:

**Caso 1**
n=0
a=[]
**llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([],0)`
Explicación: `n` es igual a 0 entra a la condicional(caso base) if y retorna `0`
Conclusión: funciona correctamente para el caso 1

**Caso 2**
n=4
a=[2,4,1,3]  //lo cambio solo para el ejemplo
**1er llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([2,4,1,3],4)`
Explicación:
       n=4 ingresa al **cuerpo**
       retorna sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],3)+a[3]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],3)+ 3 //aqui se realiza otra llamada a la misma funcion

**2da llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([1,2,3,4],3)`
Explicación:
       n=3 ingresa al **cuerpo**
       retorna sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],2)+a[2]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],2)+ 1 //aqui se realiza otra llamada a la misma funcion

**3ra llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([1,2,3,4],2)`
Explicación:
       n=2 ingresa al **cuerpo**
       retorna sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],1)+a[1]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],1)+ 4 //aqui se realiza otra llamada a la misma funcion

**4ta llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([1,2,3,4],1)`
Explicación:
       n=1 ingresa al **cuerpo**
       retorna sum(a,n-1)+a[n-1]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],0)+a[0]
       que es igual a: sum([2,4,1,3],0)+ 2 //aqui se realiza otra llamada a la misma funcion

**5ta llamada a funcion** `sum(a,n)` => `sum([1,2,3,4],0)`
Explicación:
       n=0 ingresa al **caso base**
       retorna 0; // fin de recursividad

> es aqui cuando la funcion "realiza un retroceso", toma todos los valores retornados y los suma:

```
5ta=>**0**
4ta=> 0 + 2 = **2**
3ra=> 2 + 4 = **6**
2da=> 6 + 1 = **7**
1ra=> 7 + 3 = **10**//llegamos al resultado
```

Trate de hacerlo lo mas entendible posible, espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por esta explicación tan completa porque lo que me interesa no es el ejercicio sino entender los conceptos.